# Manhua about a female lead who is abandoned by the male lead to die in a fire and then reincarnated back in time

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I'm trying to find a manhua about a female lead who is abandoned by the male lead to die and then reincarnated back in time. Here's what I remember:

- She is abandoned for another woman and dies in a fire in some sort of warehouse.
- She travels back in time to her younger self. No superpowers, I think.
- Modern times. I think the male lead was some sort of president? I don’t remember any special locations other than the fire in the warehouse at the beginning.
- Male lead also ends up reincarnating and is obsessive about her. Hurts her as he tries to woo her.
- She never loves him and leaves him in the end (I'm pretty sure at least).
- I'm pretty sure the title was "Escaping Mr. Lu" or something. Cover art was FL in a thin dress reaching to the sky and ML clinging to her waist.
- I'm pretty sure the original language was Chinese.
- I don't know if it came from a novel but I read it as a manhua.
- I don’t remember her hair colour. The male lead's hair colour was black. I think hers was too maybe?
- The art was not anything fancy.

I tried googling all this, searching on Manga Updates, and looking in my read history, but I can't find it anywhere!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this, and where?  Do you remember the names of any characters and places, or any notable details of appearances or scenery?

Comment: Thank you! I’ve edited my question to give it more detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Mr. Fu's Favorite](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/mr-fus-favorite)***...?

[image]

From Anime-Planet:

> Shen Wei Lan died for deeply loving Fu Su Mian in her last life. Now she born again and swore that she would stay far away from him! But why?! She racks her brains to stay far away from him, but he who hates her in the last life becomes strongly possessive! He claims arbitrarily, "You are mine forever! You have no where to go!"

The cover matches your description and in the first chapter, the male lead, Fu Su Man, and the female lead, Shen Wei Lan, are both in a burning warehouse, and Su Man leaves Wei Lan in a part of the building that isn't currently in flames so he can go back to save another woman, who's apparently a rival to Wei Lan for his affections.

Wei Lan ends up being burned to death and then wakes up back in her own body, ten years earlier, just before she's introduced to Su Man again by her father, who wants them to get married.

Comment: Yeah that’s it exactly! Thank you so much!